# Docker build(python image) fails due to cryptography

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am trying to build an image for my flask server, I generated the requirements.txt using pipreqs.

The requirements.txt contains `cryptography==2.8` and everytime the build fails on while trying to install this version. Not too sure why, it even shows that the version is right there.

Here is the docker build error

```
 22.90 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography==2.8 
(from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.6, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3, 2.3.1, 2.4, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.5, 2.6, 2.6.1, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 3.0, 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.2, 3.2.1, 3.3, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.4, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.4, 3.4.5, 3.4.6, 3.4.7, 3.4.8, 35.0.0, 36.0.0, 36.0.1)
#8 22.90 ERROR: No matching distribution found for cryptography==2.8
#8 22.92 WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
#8 22.92 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

EDIT :
Even without copying any of the flask code, the following build fails

```
FROM python:3.8.10-alpine3.13
RUN pip install cryptography==2.8
```

Please have a look and let me know if more info is needed or where I am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Works for me. What happens if you manually run `pip install cryptography==2.8` instead of installing from the requirements.txt file?

Comment: @K.Mat ```pip install cryptography==2.8``` works on my local machine, but not in the image while it is being built, I tried a ```RUN pip install cryptography==2.8``` in the dockerfile but it is the same result (build failed). I am using ```python:3.9.10-alpine3.15``` if it helps

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example which illustrates your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for instructions on how to do so

Comment: @Paolo I made the edit and added the dockerfile which is producing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem in with alpine linux image, I mean the base image used for building python:3.9.10-alpine3.15 you should try to install cryptography manually by following the code mentioned below:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    libressl-dev \
    musl-dev \
    libffi-dev && \
pip install --no-cache-dir cryptography==2.8 && \
apk del \
    libressl-dev \
    musl-dev \
    libffi-dev
```

[Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/) documentation also has the information as how to download it

`RUN apk add gcc musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo`

Comment: You are right, there was an issue with the base image. It works perfectly with ```python:3.8.10-slim-buster``` . The RUN command you provided did not make a difference though, it still gave the same error. Either way, any idea what is the exact issue with the previous base image?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `alpine` image does not have `gcc` installed as you can see in the complete error message (not shown in your question, but easily reproduced with docker):

```
Unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Fix it by installing gcc and the dependencies of `cryptography`:

```
FROM python:3.8.10-alpine3.13
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    build-base \
    libressl-dev \
    musl-dev \
    libffi-dev
RUN pip install cryptography==2.8
```

You might still wonder why you get the (confusing ) message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography==2.8 
(from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.6, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3, 2.3.1, 2.4, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.5, 2.6, 2.6.1, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 3.0, 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.2, 3.2.1, 3.3, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.4, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.4, 3.4.5, 3.4.6, 3.4.7, 3.4.8, 35.0.0, 36.0.0, 36.0.1)
```

The error message is simply stating the facts: `pip` could not find a version that

1. fits your requirements
2. Could be installed without error

The only version that satisfied 1. (and was downloaded, see the complete log of the installation) did not staisfy 2. and was therefore discarded. Then the error is produced with a list of all versions that pip checked against condition 1. and 2., i.e. all versions on pypi that where candidates for your OS and python version

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a problem with the base image as pointed out by @Soheb, it works perfectly with `python:3.8.10-slim-buster`. Not too sure what was the issue with the previous base image though

Comment: Did you try the second run command what was the error?